# Want to split an UNIX xml file based on tags

Tags: xml, unix, xml-parsing

I've a XML file with batches like below.

I want to split this file into 5 files based on the tags using shell scripting. 
Please help, thanks in advance.

```
<Items>
<Item>
<Title>Title 1</Title>
<DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
</Item>
<Item>
<Title>Title 2</Title>
<DueDate>01-02-2009</DueDate>
</Item>
<Item>
<Title>Title 3</Title>
<DueDate>01-02-2010</DueDate>
</Item>
<Item>
<Title>Title 4</Title>
<DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
</Item>
<Item>
<Title>Title 5</Title>
<DueDate>01-02-2012</DueDate>
</Item>
</Items>
```

Desired output:

```
<Items>
<Item>
<Title>Title 1</Title>
<DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
</Item>
</Items>
```

Comment: What does that have to do with UNIX? UNIX is kind of a standard for operating systems, whereas XML is a file format...

Comment: I'm trying to seperate individual unit from the batch & I work in UNIX OS, so I want to know how to do it using shell scripting..

Comment: @drewr2012 wonders: *Just curious as to what you are trying to gain from accomplishing this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest - install [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) which includes the rather handy [`xml_split`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_split/xml_split) utility. That may do what you need. E.g.:

```
xml_split -c Item
```

However I'd offer what you're trying to accomplish isn't amazingly easy, because you're trying to cut up and retain the XML structure. You can't do it with standard line/regex based tools.

However you *can* use a parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my @item_list;

sub cut_item {
    my ( $twig, $item ) = @_;
    my $thing = $item->cut;
    push( @item_list, $thing );

}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => { 'Item' => \&cut_item }
);
$twig->parse(<>);

my $itemcount = 1;

foreach my $element (@item_list) {
    my $newdoc = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' );
    $newdoc->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('Items') );

    $element->paste( $newdoc->root );
    $newdoc->print;
    open( my $output, ">", "items_" . $itemcount++ . ".xml" );
    print {$output} $newdoc->sprint;
    close($output);
}
```

This uses the `XML::Twig` library to extract each of the `Item` elements from your XML (piped on STDIN, or via `myscript.pl yourfilename`).

It then iterates all the ones it found, adds an `Items` header, and prints it to  a separate file. This approach might take a little more fiddling if you had a more complex root, but it is adaptable if you do.