# How to cleanup xml file on Unix using XML::Twig parser based on tags

Tags: xml, perl, unix, xml-parsing

I need to clean up XML files from unnecessary information (repeated, outdated and etc).
I have XML files with different named tags but they all share similar properties and I am looking for a solution on how to cut out some of the tags from XML file by passing arguments to Perl parser.

An example XML structure would be:

```
<Jobs>
<Job>
<JobID>ID1</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID2</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2009</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID3</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2010</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID4</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID5</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2012</DueDate>
</Job>
</Jobs>
```

Now let's say I wish to cut out `Job` tag which holds `JobID` tag with text `ID3` and my output.xml file would become:

```
<Jobs>
<Job>
<JobID>ID1</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID2</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2009</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID4</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID5</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2012</DueDate>
</Job>
</Jobs>
```

Please help me writing a code using `XML::Twig` which can help in solving this task using Perl [Based on suggestion made here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296667/want-to-split-an-unix-xml-file-based-on-tags)

I need to cut out tag at any position within the file and pull up all other tags below it and save back to the file (best to the same file).

I need to have a Perl script and pass arguments to it like this:

Have two arguments being passed onto script:

1. Name of the tag which has to be removed, lets call it `R_tag`
2. Name of the tag which is nested under R_tag, lets call it `R_tag_nested`
3. And we have to pass a value which nested tag must be equal to in order to trigger `R_tag` removal which in our case would be `ID3`

I would call the script using this line
`myscript.pl?R_tag&R_tag_nested=ID3`

But at the same time I wish to be flexible enough in order to cut out 2 or more tags in one go by sending more than one nested tag parameters (as `R_tag` is the same over the whole document) and command would be :

`myscript.pl?R_tag&R_tag_nested=ID3&R_tag_nested=ID5` which would give such output to output.xml file:

```
<Jobs>
<Job>
<JobID>ID1</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID2</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2009</DueDate>
</Job>
<Job>
<JobID>ID4</JobID>
<DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
</Job>
</Jobs>
```

I have not started writing it as I have not had much experience with cut/paste/trim of XML using XML::Twig and need help in writing this short code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't identified what is giving you a problem, so I'm going to assume you're asking how to approach the problem.

---

When you want to move filter out items from a list, a hash is useful. Build the following hash:

```perl
my %to_remove = (
   "ID3" => 1,
   "ID5" => 1,
);
```

Then, it's just a question of iterating through the nodes you might want to remove, get their text content, and deleting those
for which the following is true:

```perl
$to_remove{$text_content}
```

Comment: Yes, a good idea, and since the writing of the script was not even started - I'm still putting up the whole idea (which might be very useful for others too) in an orderly manner of what to do and how to write code properly as I may need to take an XML file 1Gb size holding 2 million nodes of JobID and then need to remove maybe 700,000 such nodes from the XML file. So it must run fast and consume minimum memory.

So the first step would be to build a hash from a list to be removed.

Comment: XML::Twig's `twig_roots` can be used to limit memory usage by only building the subtrees of interest (e.g. only have one Job in memory at a time). I'm more familiar with XML::LibXML, so I'd use XML::LibXML::Reader's `copyCurrentNode(1)` to achieve the same result instead.

Comment: I'm not attached to XML::Twig and would be happy to use anything else as long as it does the job. But I am struggling in writing the code from scratch. i can adjust/modify it to the needs later but the whole basis is slightly above my skills.